# Determine value of integral:$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, probability-limit-theorems

Determine value of integral:$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$$

I use Taylor's expansion with $x_0=0$, we have:

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}x^i}{i}$$

Hence $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}x^{i-1}}{i}dx=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i^2}$$

But, come here i don't know how! 
Please help me!
I think the result is $I=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$

Comment: "i don't know how!" You do not know what? How to justify what you wrote or how to compute the series at the end?

Comment: You don't recognize the [zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) ? Or do you want an actual proof of its value ? If the latter, see [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: @Lucian: if this is a learning exercise, then it is important to know why the summation and integration may be reversed.  It is not trivial because the sum is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Ron, I agree with your fine and subtle observations, but it doesn't seem like this is what is being asked. (Then again, I may be wrong).

Answer (score 7):

$$\zeta(2)=\sum_1^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\sum_1^\infty\frac1{(2n)^2}+\sum_0^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\zeta(2)}4+\sum_0^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2}$$

The sum of odds is thus $\frac34$ of the total, which is [$\frac{\pi^2}6$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), namely $\frac{\pi^2}8$. Your sum is the difference of the two, $\frac{\pi^2}8-\frac{\pi^2}{24}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.